# Problems when "Building" a WCF REST Service with a Reference to another project

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, build-process

I have a solution with two projects:

1. DataAccessLayer project - A self explanatory class library, which has a reference to .NET MySql connector dlls and able to save it's settings to a Settings file, .
2. WebService project - has the WCF REST service which has a reference to the DataAccessLayer project.

After I build the "WebService" project (in 'Release' mode) I cannot locate both the DataAccessLayer.dll.config file and MySql.Data.dll file in the "WebService" Release folder.

**UPDATE:**
Well, after some experimenting I figured that setting "MySql.Data.dll" reference's "Copy Local" property to true in the "DataAccessLayer" project, copies it to the DataAccessLayer "Release Folder" on build. But still, when building the "WebService" project - the only files I see in the "WebService"'s bin\Release folder are the "DataAccessLayer.dll" file, the "WebService.dll" file and their relative ".pdb" files. (still no MySql.Data.dll and DataAccessLayer.dll.config).

**UPDATE 2:**
Ok, not sure there's a more elegant or better solution but I ended up adding a "Post-Build" event (Project Properties -> Build Events) to the "WebService" project, which copies the two files from the "DataAccessLayer" output directory to the "WebService" output directory, in the following manner:

```
copy "$(SolutionDir)DataAccessLayer\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\MySql.Data.dll" "$(TargetDir)" &
copy "$(SolutionDir)DataAccessLayer\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\DataAccessLayer.dll.config" "$(TargetDir)"
```

If anyone thinks of a more generic way of doing this, please let me know!

Thanks,

Mikey

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the MySQL.Data.dll is referenced by the DataAccessLayer project. If that's the case, go to the reference and open up its properties. There should be an option that says Copy Local, double check that it's set to true (I think it defaults to false). And if that isn't the issue, you can try referencing the dll in the WebService project also, which should copy it over. Or you could add the DLL to the GAC or, worst case scenario, you can always just copy the files over manually (as long as it's in the bin directory, it should find it), but that would suck long term.

Comment: You must've missed my update.
Yes, the MySql.Data.dll is being referenced in the DataAccessLayer project, and it shows up only in the "DataAccessLayer" Release folder, after "Building" it... but not in the "WebService" Release folder, which is what i'm after.

copying the dll to GAC is not an option, since the IIS is a shared server (not mine).

copying the files manually does seem to do the trick, but I'm really after a more elegant solution if possible.